# How to close Appium driver properly in Python?

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am using Python 3.7 with Appium 1.15.1 on real Android Device.
When my script finish the job, I close the driver with these lines:

```
if p_driver:
    p_driver.close()
```

but I get this error ouput:

```
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 688, in close
    self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
    raise wde
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 24, in check_response
    super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 404 - undefined
```

I would like to understand what  I am doing wrong?
What is the way to close properly the driver?
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** you should get the appium session dictionary first:

```
session_instance = webdriver.Remote(str(url), caps_dic)
```

where *url* is your appium server url. something like: `"http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"`
and *caps_dic* is a dictionary of all your desired capabilities

**Step2:** you run the quit() method on session:

```
session_instance[session].quit()
```

**So the whole snippet is:**

```
session_instance = webdriver.Remote(str(url), caps_dic)
session_instance[session].quit()
```